# CSSTransition HoC for reusable modals which render through a React Portal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref, react-portal, react-hoc

I've written a simple `useModal` hook which allows me to quickly put together a modal using dynamic content. It works great and all but now there's a problem: I've used the excellent `CSSTransition` library to introduce some subtle animations when showing/hiding the modal;

However the animation is not working and I'm struggling to figure out why. I've put together a very small code sample to showcase the problem and help you help me.

Thanks in advance

[codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/ultimatemodals-zfpxfc?file=/src/ModalShowcase.jsx)